# Convert matplotlib color value to RGB

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, color-conversion

I want to convert  color value in this format `((0.19215686274509805, 0.5098039215686274, 0.7411764705882353))` to RGB value.

I tried the following,

```
    import matplotlib
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    cycler = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20c.colors)()

    color = next(cycler)['color']
    color_rgb = matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(color) # <--
```

The last line, `to_rgb(color)` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error, or an otherwise unexpected result? When I run your code, I get `color = (0.19215686274509805, 0.5098039215686274, 0.7411764705882353)`, which to me seems like a correct value for that colormap.

Comment: @OrOrg Please check my edit. The output `color_rgb` is same as the input `color`.

Comment: `to_rgb(c)` converts whatever `c` is (can be many things as long as it relates to color: a hex string, name, ...) into an RGB tuple with values in the range [0,1]. But in your case `c` is already an RGB tuple, so nothing extra happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is that your statement:

> The last line, `to_rgb(color)` doesn't work.

is not true.

As OrOrg already commented:

> to_rgb(c) converts whatever c is (can be many things as long as it
> relates to color: a hex string, name, ...) into an RGB tuple with
> values in the range [0,1]. But in your case c is already an RGB tuple,
> so nothing extra happens.

What you expect is to get the RGB values as integers or a string with a hex-code what can be done as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cycler = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20c.colors)()
color = next(cycler)["color"]

color_rgb = tuple([int(c*255) for c in color])  # <--
print(color_rgb)     # gives (49, 130, 189)
color_rgb_hex = '#%02x%02x%02x' % color_rgb     # <--
print(color_rgb_hex) # gives '#3182bd'
```

The matplotlib `.to_hex()` works as by you expected :

```
color_rgb_hex_by_matplotlib = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(color)
print(color_rgb_hex_by_matplotlib) # gives '#3182bd'
```

The matplotlib `.to_rgb()` drops only the alpha channel from the to it passed color see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgb.html)